# logical proof approach for a theorem from Rick's Essentials of Stochastic Processes

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

[image]

[page-186-Essentials of Stochastic Processes](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/EOSP/EOSP2021.pdf)

Q1 From **Theorem 6.1(ii)** I can tell matrix $A$ is linearly dependent. Since it said exactly one of the following holds, I proposed **(i)** can imply matrix $A$ is linearly independent, but I cannot prove this. (I can do another way around) $\color{blue}{\text{I am still keen to know if (i) can implies linearly independent}}$

Q2 My second attempt was trying to negate **(ii)** to see if I can get linearly independent, the statement becomes "for all probability vector $p_j\leq 0$ such that $\sum^{n}_{j=1}a_{i,j}p_j\neq 0$" then this is a nonsense if all $p_j=0$ Why is this happens? **(not sure if my logic negation is correct)**

---

I came up with this logical idea to proof that *exactly one of them is true*

Please let me know if this admissible

let statement **(ii)** be $P$, I could get $P\implies Q$(linearly dependent).

From $\neg Q$(linearly independent)$\implies R\,$($R$ is statement **(i)**)

Also $\neg Q\implies \neg P$, so that $\neg P\equiv R$, then $(P\land R)$ is always a contradiction.

Comment: Your negation is incorrect. Rewrite it carefully and use the negation rules.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan what about this one? for all $p_j>0$ and $\sum^n_{j=1} a_{i,j} p_j\neq 0$ for some $i$

Comment: Yes, that's right (together with the condition that $p_j$ is a probability vector).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you for your reply. If you don't mind, would you please check out my **Q1**. It seems my second attempt is not helpful in this question

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Hi, Sorry to bother you again. I just came up with an idea above, would you please check out if that is admissible, Cheers