# How do I know what should be negated in a negation? Example: $\forall x\geq 0,\text{such that}\, xy\geq 0\, \forall y\geq 0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I made up this example and this leads to a nonsense.

$$\forall x\geq 0,\text{such that}\, xy\geq 0\, \forall y\geq 0$$

Then the negation becomes

$$\exists x<0,\text{such that}\,xy<0\,\text{for some}\,y<0$$

What goes wrong? How should I know what should be negated?

Comment: Your first displayed line is not a statement.It does not say something which might be true or false. So it cannot even have a negation.

Comment: "∀x≥0,such that xy≥0 ∀y≥0" is simply; $∀x≥0,∀y≥0 \ xy≥0$. Thus, put the negation in front (the negation sign acts on statements) and "move in" (if necessary) using the equivalence: $\lnot \forall x$ and $\exists x \lnot$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for your reply. I am still confusing why negation not in relation $x\geq 0$ and $y\geq 0$ but only in $xy\geq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first equation the second quantifier is in a confusing place and, as I'll discuss below, the notation "$\forall x \ge 0$" is not a good idea in this context. It should read

$$\forall x, y : x \ge 0, y \ge 0 \Rightarrow xy \ge 0$$

which is true. We negate this as follows. The negation of $\forall x : P(x)$ is $\exists x : \neg P(x)$, and the negation of $p \Rightarrow q$ is $p \text{ and } \neg q$. This gives

$$\exists x, y : x \ge 0, y \ge 0 \text{ and } xy < 0$$

which is false, as expected. You only need to consistently apply a small set of rules about how negation works (the above plus [de Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), together with existential quantifiers negating to universal quantifiers, is enough), all of which you can figure out by thinking about exactly what is necessary for a statement to be false.

Writing "$\forall x \ge 0$" is notationally convenient sometimes but when it's time to be precise it's better not to write things like this exactly because it gets more confusing how to apply these formal rules about how to negate things. There is an implication, which has been written explicitly above, which gets hidden with this notation.

Comment: You changed OP's first displayed line into something which you then addressed. But how do you know that's what OP intended?

Comment: Would you please check out this negation?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4531068/linearly-independent-intuition-behind-the-theorem-from-ricks-essentials-of-sto

Comment: Isn't it obvious? You just have to move the $\forall y \ge 0$ slightly and you get a recognizable statement that could easily be the subject of an exercise in a textbook.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan "could be an exercise in textbook"--- OP explicitly said he/she made up the example.