# Is admissible to use truth table to validate this claim

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose the question requires to proof two contradictory statements $A$ and $B$. If I can deduce $$B\implies P\\\neg P\implies A$$ Then can I claim  $A\equiv\neg B\\$?

Moreover, If this statement always true?

$$((B\implies P)\land(\neg P\implies A))\implies(B\land A)\equiv\bot$$

The relevant question is here [logical proof approach for a theorem from Rick's Essentials of Stochastic Processes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4531068/logical-proof-approach-for-a-theorem-from-ricks-essentials-of-stochastic-proces)

Comment: I'd say the first claim is false since false can imply anything ($P=1$ doesn't tell us anything about A). Same for the second claim. $B=1, P=1$ can lead to $A=1$ or $A=0$

Comment: If you want to test the validity of an argument expressed in a few short formulas of classical propositional logic involving only a small handful of atoms (three, in your case), filling out a truth table is a perfectly good strategy.

Comment: Using a truth table, both claims can be shown to be false when A, B and P are all true.